# Wordpress best action/filter for implementation of custom access rules

Tags: php, wordpress

Where is the best place for access control rules? I need a place (filter or action),
in where these thing works :

- I still can redirect, so nothing is sent to output yet.
- Global objects with displayed content are already resolved, that means I know from `$post`, `$page` and other globals, which post/page/cathegory will be displayed.
- Place is bullet proof, when someone change permalinks (different URL path pieces).

P.S.: I must have absolute control over access rules, so I won't accept a 3rd party solution (some recommended plugin), I simply want to write it myself (various valid reasons).

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Codex action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

The 'wp' action is called when the WP object is setup, but before output, so this should fit your requirements.

This hook fires on both the front-end and in admin, so you may need to control it based on your needs e.g.  `if( is_admin() )`

Comment: thx, looks promissing ... I'll check it out once I return from my vacation xD